# Change Password length in Membership API

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My `RegisterModel` has the `Password` Property as below:

```
 public class RegisterModel
 {  
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 8)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
 }
```

In Register View, I have this:

```
<p class="message-info">
Passwords must be at least @Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength characters long.
</p>
```

Though, I have changed the `MinimumLength` of `Password` to `8` characters in my `RegisterModel`, still it is showing only `6` on my view page as shown in screenshot below:

[image: This is default application in MVC , I am accessing this page by account/register address.My host address is local.]

How to change `Password` Length?

Comment: FYI: The current proposed answer(date 2/6/13) does not work for MVC 5...sadly I don't, yet, know what does.  Thought I'd post this in case someone else comes looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you have changed it in your `RegisterModel`, notice that on your `Register View`, the value is coming from `Membership` class that is configured according to your `Membership` `Provider` in your `web.config` file.

So, Check your `web.config` file. It has the following code:

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"          
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6"                  //Change This
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Change `minRequiredPasswordLength = "8"` here too and it will work for you.

**OR**

If you don't want to make changes in your `Membership Provider`, then you can still do this by writing your own Custom Attribute for `MinPasswordLength` as below:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter , AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class MinRequiredPasswordLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{                             
    private readonly int _minimumLength = Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength;
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString, name, _minimumLength);
    }    

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {                    
        string password = value.ToString();    
        return password.Length >= this._minimumLength; 
    } 
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) 
    {       
        return new[]{ new ModelClientValidationStringLengthRule(FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()), _minimumLength, int.MaxValue)
        };
    }
}
```

Then update your `RegisterModel` to use the `MinRequiredPasswordLength` DataAnnotation instead.

```
[Required]        
[MinRequiredPasswordLength(ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {1} character(s) long.")]           
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

- See more at: http://timjames.me/mvc-3-password-length-dataannotation#sthash.kxyHoPep.dpuf

Comment: So it does mean that it is calling membership directly from web.config , Can't we get password length from Registermodel?

Comment: Still don't get why the two are so disjointed in MVC :|

Comment: @TimBJames Even if you changed it in your code, your Membership will use this string for configuration, so it should also be changed with the code. Neither alone can help you out...