# Change password length in MVC 5 Membership

Tags: .net, simplemembership, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Trying to change the default minimum password length to 4 characters.  I know, 4!!! Ridiculous, right! Not my call.

Anyway, I've changed it on the `RegisterViewModel` but that doesn't actually change it. To illustrate I've posted the code below.  The `ModleState.IsValid` returns correctly based on the updated ViewModel.  However it then calls `UserManager.CreateAsync()` which returns `False` with an error message of "Passwords must be at least 6 characters"

I've followed the steps in this, very, similar post([Change Password...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721378/change-password-length-in-membership-api)) but it does not work for MVC 5 as far I as I can tell.  It still returns the same message.

```
//
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, LastLogin = model.LastLogin };


// This is where it 'fails' on the CreateAsync() call
                    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                }
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you can see `UserManager` has public property `IIdentityValidator<string> PasswordValidator` for password validation which is currently initialized in `UserManager`'s constructor with hardcoded parameter `this.PasswordValidator = (IIdentityValidator<string>) new MinimumLengthValidator(6);`.

You can set this property with `MinimumLengthValidator` object with required password length.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the password properties using the PasswordValidator found in the IdentityConfig.cs file in the App_Start Directory.

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the following article at MSDN

[Implementing custom password policy using ASP.NET Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/01/06/implementing-custom-password-policy-using-asp-net-identity.aspx)

The suggestion here is to extend the `UserManager` class in the application and setting the `PasswordValidator` property in the contructor:

```
public class MyUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyUserManager() : 
        base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
    {
        PasswordValidator = new MinimumLengthValidator(4);
    }
}
```

And then in your controller (or controllers base class) instantiate `MyUserManager`:

```
public BaseController() : this(new MyUserManager())
{
}

public BaseController(MyUserManager userManager)
{
  UserManager = userManager;
}

public MyUserManager UserManager { get; private set; }
```

You may also implement a custom validator to check more complex password rules by implementing `IIdentityValidator` and replacing the default validator.