# In mvc 5 AspNet.Identity.Core I cannot find UserManager default (hardcoded) parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In MVC 5 AccountController ther is a UserManager Class with goto definition I can see the sorce code but I cannot find a way to get to the hardcoded default values/parameters like MinimumLength (which is 6) or the Errormessage if the PW is shorter (Passwords should be at least 6 characters long.)

I know that these values cannot be changed in the reference dll's and I with the help of this forum I manged to change the value in the AccountController:

```
    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;

        UserManager.PasswordValidator = new MinimumLengthValidator(8);
    }
```

but I really want know where and how to find these values so that I know about them in the future!

p.s. Alex K. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19732555/3152110 tells in his answer that " UserManager's constructor with hardcoded parameter is 
        this.PasswordValidator = (IIdentityValidator) new MinimumLengthValidator(6);"
but he didn't tell where or how he found this line of code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open the dll with ILspy.exe http://ilspy.net/
you can see source code

Comment: Good idea ... I actually found it with ilspy: this.PasswordValidator = new MinimumLengthValidator(6); But is there really no way to see this directly in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Resharper (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Navigate_from_Here__Decompiled_Code.html) and reflector.net/category/visual-studio has this feature.