# .Net Identity 2 custom validation text

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

How can i write custom text for 'password minimumlength' and 'username exist' error text ?

```
UserManager.PasswordValidator = new MinimumLengthValidator(4);
```

I am getting "Passwords must be at least 6 characters." error although i set minimumlength to 4 and change error message.
it must be local language as i have written.

I tried this aspect but not work.

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Şifreniz en az 4 karakter olmalıdır.", MinimumLength = 4)]
```

here is my model property for password

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Şifre girmediniz")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Şifreniz en az 4 karakter olmalıdır.", MinimumLength = 4)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Şifre")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: what didn't work about it? Please clarify your question.

Comment: are you getting the default error message instead?

Comment: yes i m getting default error message which is in framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably due to Membership Provider constraint. 
Please see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.minrequiredpasswordlength(v=vs.110).aspx) also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14721427/492258)

Comment: membership node doesnt exist in my congif files ?

Comment: Then you could add those lines and and edit relevant value. İyi şanşlar

Comment: 2 validators check my password if i write 4 digit it says password must be at least 5 this is my validation and it works..but if i write 5 digit it says password must be at least 6. i cant find where is the second validator

Comment: the second is occured after this line run UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)

Comment: I think once you can override password min length then you can override requirement message.

Comment: yes it works. i ovverride password min on usermanager.
added this line before create
UserManager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator { RequiredLength = 5 };
teşekkürler : )